# How to apply functions on grouped elements in dplyr while keeping part of the data

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

## Problem summary

At the moment, I am trying to apply a function that computes in some way a lagged data, this function has to be applied on various sets of groups and I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this with Dplyr.

## Expected result

As an example the data would look like this:

```
   date group value
1 Jan 1     A     0
2 Feb 1     A     1
3 Mar 1     A     0
4 Jan 1     B     2
5 Feb 1     B     4
6 Mar 1     B     0
```

And the idea is to get such output like, for example a rolling mean on 2 months:

```
   date group value roll_mean
1 Feb 1     A     1       0.5
2 Mar 1     A     0       0.5
3 Feb 1     B     4         3
4 Mar 1     B     0         2
```

## Reproducible example

I have prepared an example, usable in R, with the data and a function, for the sake of the example:

```
data <- data.frame(
  date = as.yearmon(
    as.Date(
        c("01/01/2020", "01/02/2020", "01/03/2020", "01/01/2020", "01/02/2020", "01/03/2020"),
        origin = "1970-01-01")
    ),
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  value = c(0, 1, 0, 2, 4, 0)
)

computing_function <- function(data) {
  output_data <- data %>% 
    mutate(
      roll_mean = rollmean(data$value, k = 2, fill = NA, align="right")
    ) %>% 
    drop_na(roll_mean)
  return (output_data)
}
```

## Question

I see how to do it with loops, but this would be time consuming, not reliable and a pain to maintain. The output for a group for example works. However I can't make it work within Dplyr, even when using [summarise()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html). I am missing something in my logic and I can't pinpoint what it is.

```
computing_function(data %>% filter(group == "B"))
#    date group value roll_mean
# 1 Feb 1     B     4         3
# 2 Mar 1     B     0         2

data %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(computing_function(.))
# Error
```

Would there be a way to do it dplyr-wise that would make sense ?

*The logic of the function should stay in it, the idea is not to offset it to the dplyr expression.*

#### Packages used:

- Dplyr
- Zoo

Answer (score 1):

`summarise` is not the right function since it returns one row per group.
Moreover, your function gets a data.frame as input, which will not work inside `summarise` or `mutate`. You either want something like this, which takes a vector as input:

```
computing_function1 <- function(values) {
    rollmean(values, k = 2, fill = NA, align="right")
}

data %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(roll_mean = computing_function1(value)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(roll_mean))
```

Or if you really want to keep the same structure, you have to split the dataset, apply the function on the 'groups' and reassemble the dataset:

```
data %>%
  split(.$group) %>% 
  map_dfr( computing_function )
```

Comment: Good answer, I didn't think about it this way, I found a more dplyr solution after intensely looking into the subject, which I'll put here in a few moments.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this situation can be found in the documentation of Dplyr with the function [`modify_by`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html). It is a purrr-style function that enables use of function over data frames (and tibbles by extension).

This function allows the input to be a tibble and the output to be a grouped tibble.
Here is an answer with Dplyr code and logic:

```
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  group_modify(~computing_function(.x))

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
# # Groups:   group [2]
#   group date      value roll_mean
#   <chr> <yearmon> <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 A     Feb 1         1       0.5
# 2 A     Mar 1         0       0.5
# 3 B     Feb 1         4       3  
# 4 B     Mar 1         0       2
```

You can use `ungroup()` after the `group_modify()` expression for outputing a non-grouped tibble to pass to further functions if need be.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Use `read.zoo` to convert `data` to a wide form zoo object which has a row for each date and a column for each group.  Then use `rollmeanr` (same as `rollmean` but defaults to `align="right"`) and create a complex object consisting of the original values as the real part and the means as the imaginary part.  Use fortify.zoo to melt that back to a long form data frame and extract the real and imaginary parts out.  This only uses magrittr pipes and zoo.

```
data %>%
  read.zoo(split = "group") %>%
  { fortify.zoo(. + rollmeanr(., 2) * 1i, melt = TRUE, names = names(data)) } %>%
  transform(value = Re(value), rollmean = Im(value))
```

giving:

```
      date group value rollmean
1 Feb 0001     A     1      0.5
2 Mar 0001     A     0      0.5
3 Feb 0001     B     4      3.0
4 Mar 0001     B     0      2.0
```

**2)** A variation of the above would be the following. It calculates a wide zoo object of the means and then converts it back to a long form data frame and merges the value column back in.  The last line of code could be omitted if you don't really need the value column in the result and the second last could be omitted if a zoo object of means is sufficient.

```
data %>%
   read.zoo(split = "group") %>%
   rollmeanr(2) %>%
   fortify.zoo(melt = TRUE, names = c(names(data)[1:2], "rollmean")) %>%
   merge(data, ., by = 2:1)
```

Comment: While I agree that this is a good way to apply that specific function, I was looking at something that would use exclusively Dplyr while keeping the original function. The reason being that my real life application uses a much more complex function that has somewhat the same effect on the data.

Comment: There isn't anything specific to rollmeanr here other than it inputs and outputs a zoo object but even that could be relaxed depending on what you have. The calculation itself can be arbitrarily complex.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your input. However, as stated in my question, I need the *function to stay as it is* and find a dplyr way to do this calculation. The idea being to input a grouped `data.frame` and outputs a `data.frame`.